# Skyrim Wearable Lantern Mod and Hunterborn Crafting Lantern oil

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I am playing Skyrim with the poplar mods: Campfire, Frostfall, Hunterborn, Wearable lanterns and others.

I have been told all over other forums that it is possible with Hunterborn to be able to craft the HB animal fat item into lantern oil for the Wearable Lanterns mod.

So far I have not been able to find a way to do that with any of the intuitive crafting methods. Can anyone give me insight as to how this should work?

Comment: Have you installed any compatibility patches? Sometimes popular mods that are commonly used together will have these so that users can use them together. I'd recommend carefully reading the Nexus Forum mod pages and looking at the downloads tab (assuming you're using the NMM).

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the other mods and using just the two in question? One of the other mods may be interfering somehow.

Comment: I have tweaked my load order a bit. all of the other recipes for both mods is showing up. So I don't think its one mod overwriting the crafting tables. It would be nice if someone who does have it working properly would be able to comment to tell me exactly where it should be crafted because I can't find anything about the specifics anywhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months I found a mod on the Nexus that fixes the issue that I am having.

http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/8059/?

It says its for special edition, however it works with normal Skyrim.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you found what you were after, but Lantern Oil is crafted at cooking spits in taverns or anywhere else that has a cooking spit. The conversion rate is 4:1 fat to oil.